# Display Values from Custom Tables in wordpress Admin Panel

Tags: wordpress

I would like to display some values from custom tables in wordpress. This is what I've got so far. I am not sure this is all completely correct.

```
function pr_forms() {
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = pr_table_name();

    return $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id,name,place FROM $table_name" );
}
```

This will return multiple rows as an array. I tried using a foreach. But no use...it just gives an error.

Any suggestions how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This works**

```
function pr_forms() {
  global $wpdb;

  $table_name = pr_table_name();

  $rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id,name,place FROM $table_name" );
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row->id."<br>";
    echo $row->name."<br>";
    echo $row->place."<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    }
}
```